# FadeIn/Out based on scroll height

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I have the following which should make `.secondLogo` appear (by fading in) when `scrollToTop` is past 1000px

```
var secondLogo = $(".secondLogo");
$(window).scroll(function(){
  //more then or equals to
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= 1000 ){
       secondLogo.fadeIn();

  //less then 1000px from top
  } else {
     secondLogo.fadeOut();

  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="secondLogo">
    <img src="images/smm_logo_large.png" alt="Student Makers Market logo"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.secondLogo{
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-10;
    top: 15%;
    left: 3%;
    opacity:0.1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=10); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.fn.fadeIn` and `$.fn.fadeOut` do not manipulate the css property `opacity`. Initialize your element with `display:none` instead

```
.secondLogo {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -10;
    top: 15%;
    left: 3%;
}
```